# AvalonDock causing crash when a document is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm currently facing a very odd problem. I'm using AvalonDock (embedded in the last WPF Extended Toolkit 3) on a WPF application with Caliburn.Micro.

In my **MainView.xml** I have this DockingManager:

```
<xcad:DockingManager x:Name="dockMngr"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     AllowMixedOrientation="True"
                     DataContext="{Binding DockingManagerVM}"
                     DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                     AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}"
                     ActiveContent="{Binding CurrentDocument, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event DocumentClosed] = [Action DocumentClosed($eventArgs)];
                                         [Event DocumentClosing] = [Action DocumentClosing($eventArgs)]">
```

In the constructor of the **DockingManagerVM.cs** I create some default documents to be displayed:

```
Documents = new ObservableCollection<GenericDocumentViewModel>();
Documents.Add(new MyDocumentViewModel());
Documents.Add(new MyDocumentViewModel());
Documents.Add(new MyDocumentViewModel());
CurrentDocument = _documents[0];
```

Obviously I defined the "mapping" between MyDocumentViewModel and the view to be displayed as a document in the XAML:

```
<xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyDocumentViewModel}" >
        <local:MyDocumentView />
    </DataTemplate>
</xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
```

For some reason when I try to close a document that I didn't made active before (by clicking on the corresponding tab) the application crashes with this message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Unfortunately no details are provided from Visual Studio (if you have any idea how to get them it will be great).

The following are steps I tried to reproduce (or not) the issue:

Run the application; there are 3 documents, the first one is active and shown, then:

1. I close the second or third document by clicking the "X" on the tab control; the application **crashes**
2. I open the second document (without closing the first one); I can then close both the first and second document, but if I try to close the last one (since I didn't open it) the application **crashes**
3. I close the first document, then the second document is marked as active and shown. I close this current document, the third document is shown and I can close this one. **No crash**.
4. I open all the documents by clicking on the tab menu, one by one; then I can close each document in any order **without crashing**.
5. I right-click the tab control and click on "Close all documents" (this feature is provided by AvalonDock): all the documents close **without any crash**.

Could you please tell me if you notice something wrong in what I am doing or if is there any way to debug AvalonDock in order to figure out what is going on?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! It seems like this is a bug related to AvalonDock 3.0.0 (provided with Extended.WPF.Toolkit 3.0.0).

From the NuGet manager I installed Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock (version 3.2.16567.21060) that fixed the problem.

After that, since I imported an [external VS2013 theme](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonDock.Themes.VS2013/), NuGet automatically switched to Xceed.Wpf.Avalondock 2.9.15603.14400, and it works properly as well. :)